# htaccess file isn't redirecting all links to https and isn't hiding parts of the url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, http, https

I have been modifying my htaccess file of my site to do the following:

1. No one should access the base url (example.com) and anyone trying to
   access it should be redirected to example.com/site/
2. Force https on all links including urls in sub folders and sub sub folders
3. Hide /site/ in the url name that is displayed

Https redirection happens, but I can also access the http version of any page by manually changing https to http. Also I'm unable to hide /site/ from the url that gets displayed in the address bar. And no, I don't have access to the vhosts file.

Here's how I have modified my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/$1 [L,NC,R]
</IfModule>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you hosting other domains, other than `example.com` or `www.example.com` that you don't want redirected? Presumably your internal links don't contain the `/site/` subdirectory?

Comment: There are no subdomains. Site is just a folder in the root directory and everything is inside that folder. So all internal links have to go through example.com/site/.*

Comment: Well if you want 3), then you don’t want an external redirect – yet you set the `R` flag on that rule.

Comment: If you don’t need to handle any _other_ domains there, then why are you explicitly checking for `example.com` / `www.example.com` to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So all internal links have to go through `example.com/site/.*`

If you wish to "hide" the `/site` subdirectory from the URL then you need to actually *remove* the `/site` URL-path segment from all your internal hyperlinks. If the `/site` part is present in the link then all your users can see it (on the page and in the status bar - before clicking the link), so it's not "hidden" at all.

> 1. No one should access the base URL (`example.com`) and anyone trying to access it should be redirected to `example.com/site/`
> 2. Force https on all links including urls in sub folders and sub sub folders
> 3. Hide `/site/` in the URL name that is displayed

No.1 and no.3 are a contradiction. You can't "redirect" to "/site" (#1) *and* hide the `/site` URL-path segment (#3). The "redirect" would *expose* the `/site` subdirectory.

In fact, everyone *should* access the base URL. `/site` is not present in the URL (having removed it from all your internal hyperlinks). You then *internally rewrite* all requests directed at the base URL to the `/site` subdirectory. This is entirely internal to the server - the user is not aware of this. This is not an *external* "redirect", it is an *internal* "rewrite".

The actual processs is therefore:

1. Force HTTPS for all URLs.
2. Internally rewrite all requests for the base URL (eg. `example.com/` and `example.com/foo`) to the `/site` subdirectory (eg. `/site/` and `/site/foo` respectively).

However, there is an optional #0 step, if this is a URL structure that is changing - in order to preserve SEO and accidental access. And that is to "redirect" *direct* requests for the `/site` subdirectory back to the root. But this should *only* be implemented if you have already removed `/site` from all your internal hyperlinks - otherwise the user is going to be externally redirected on every click, which is "slow" for your users and will impact your server. We also have to be careful of redirect loops and only redirect *direct* requests from the user and not rewritten requests by Apache.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [OR]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/$1 [L,NC,R]
> ```

If you only have `example.com` and `www.example.com` (as you've stated in comments) then there is no need for all the hostname checks (ie. `HTTP_HOST`) - these are also duplicated, so you're checking the same thing more than once here.

The condition that checks `%{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)` will always fail ("not anything" is always false). It's only because the condition is OR'd that the rule is able to do anything.

The last `RewriteRule` unconditionally "redirects" everything to the `/site` subdirectory. This will expose the `/site` subdirectory. You would also expect this to create an endless redirect loop, unless you have another `.htaccess` file in the `/site` subdirectory that prevents this.

`^(.*)$` - there is no need to capture the URL-path, if you are not making use of the backreference in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*. In your HTTP to HTTPS redirect, this could be simplified to just `^` - as it simply needs to succeed for every request.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

# 1. HTTP to HTTPS redirect (same host)
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# 2. Internally rewrite all requests to the /site subdirectory
#    Except for requests that are already for the /site subdirectory - prevent rewrite loop
RewriteRule !^site/ /site%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

No need for the `<IfModule>` wrapper.

And, optionally, externally redirect direct requests for the `/site` subdirectory back to the root (canonical URL). NB: Only if all internal hyperlinks have had the `/site` subdirectory removed from the URL. This would go *before* the above directives.

```
# 0. Redirect direct /site requests back to the root
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^site/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The condition that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is (probably) required in order to prevent a redirect loop, since we don't want to redirect the already rewritten request by rule #2.

It is preferable to first test with 302 (temporary) redirects in order to avoid potential caching issues.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

Also consider canonicalisaing the www subdomain.

---

**UPDATE#1:** To be able to access other files in the document root or files outside of the `/site` subdirectory then you'll need to add a condition to rule#2 to exclude requests that map directly to files. For example:

```
# 2. Internally rewrite all requests to the /site subdirectory
#    Except for requests that are already for the /site subdirectory - prevent rewrite loop
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^site/ /site%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

> **UPDATE#2:** I now lost access to a password protected directory at `example.com/site2`. It redirects to `/site` and says "file not found".

You could either make an exception just for this one subdirectory. For example, edit the above rule like this:

```
# 2. Internally rewrite all requests to the /site subdirectory
#    Except for requests that are already for the /site or /site2 subdirectories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^(site|site2) /site%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

OR, make an exception for all directories, except for the root directory, which would still need to be rewritten to `/site/` in order to server your homepage. For example:

```
# 2. Internally rewrite all requests to the /site subdirectory
#    Except for requests that are already for the /site subdirectory
#    Or any [sub]directory...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^site /site%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: This works very well, But other folders or files in the root, that are not part of the 'site' subdirectory cannot be accessed. For eg., A file like hello.php which is in the root folder can't be accessed through example.com/hello.php. Also example.com/site/wp-login.php causes too many redirects and fails

Comment: If you have files outside of the `/site` subdirectory that need to be accessible over HTTP then you'll need to add a condition to rule#2 to exclude direct file requests. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Only I can't access the backend of my site folder where wordpress is installed.. https://www.example.com/site/wp-login.php goes into a redirect loop towards https://www.example.com/wp-login.php and vice versa, and says file not found.

Comment: Ah, there was an error in #2 RewriteRule! Try changing `RewriteRule !^site/ /site/$1 [L]` to `RewriteRule !^site/ /site%{REQUEST_URI} [L]`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Somehow I now lost access to a password protected directory at example.com/site2 It redirects to /site and says file not found

Comment: If you are requesting the subdirectory directly then you'll need to add another exception to either exclude that directory specifically or all directories (if you have more). I've updated my answer.